# Reporting services: Cover page header

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that already has an existing header. I need to add some info to just the cover page header.

So I added everything in a rectangle. Then hid the rectangle on everything but the first page.

```
=Globals.PageNumber <> 1
```

That works... but now I have a giant white space in place of the rectangle. The rectangle contains images and some textboxes.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving the rectangle to the first page and then hiding the header on only the first page.

Answer (score 0):

Is there actual data on the first page? If there doesn't need to be, try putting the 'Extra' items rectangle in the body of the report and add a page break afterward. Then, this rectangle will basically be a cover page for the report.